# How to store values returned by a link/webpage in a php variable

Tags: php, database

I've an array which is returned from a page have values something like this.

```
 {"Status":"Success","Details":"ae339d55-a167-11e7-94da-0200cd936042"};
```

What I want is to store the value **ae339d55-a167-11e7-94da-0200cd936042** in a variable $var.
I've tried this.

```
        $var=$arr[4];
```

Comment: Why "4"? Looks like it should be `$arr["Details"]`, although that is not valid syntax for defining an array in PHP.

Comment: [Some essential reading on how to define arrays and access their elements](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: `$var=json_decode($arr)->Details`;

Comment: even if it was a valid php array .. it would be 3 as array indexes start at 0

Comment: @rickdenhaan i've changed something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to deal with JSON array you need to convert it to PHP array with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function

```
$arr = json_decode('{"Status":"Success","Details":"ae339d55-a167-11e7-94da-0200cd936042"}', true);
$var = $arr['Details']; // "ae339d55-a167-11e7-94da-0200cd936042"
```